# How to pause all running threads? and then resume?

Tags: java, multithreading

**I have already seen this question** : [How pause and then resume a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758346/how-pause-and-then-resume-a-thread)

I have seen many questions in stackoverflow related to my issue, but I couldn't understand them because they are abstract and not specific enough to my sitiuation.

There are 2 Count Down Labels. When you click `Start Button`, the countdown is executed. In the same way, when you click `Pause Button`, it should be paused. However, I am getting an error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`

2 Threads are started, but I can't stop it with the `wait()` method. Please let me know how can I stop threads, and implement `resume` button. Thanks. Easy Example below

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

class FirstCountDown extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

public Integer doInBackground() {
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    CountDown.count1.setText(String.valueOf(1000-i));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } 
    return null;
}
}

class SecondCountDown extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

public Integer doInBackground(){
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        CountDown.count2.setText(String.valueOf(1000-i));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return null;
}
}

class CountDown extends JFrame  {

static JLabel count1;
static JLabel count2; 
static JButton startButton;
static JButton pauseButton;
static JButton resumeButton;
FirstCountDown first = new FirstCountDown();
SecondCountDown second = new SecondCountDown();

public CountDown(){
count1 = new JLabel("1000");
count2 = new JLabel("1000");
startButton = new JButton("start");
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        first.execute();
        second.execute();
    }
});
pauseButton = new JButton("pause");
pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            first.wait();
            second.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

resumeButton = new JButton("resume");

setSize(300,100);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
add(count1);
add(count2);
add(startButton);
add(pauseButton);
add(resumeButton);
setVisible(true);

        }

public static void main(String args[]) {

    CountDown g = new CountDown();

}
}
```

Comment: The way you're trying to use wait is wrong. 1) The thread that you want to 'pause' is the one that waits and 2) wait must be in a synchronized block. I wrote a more complete code example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443806/pausing-threads-in-java/20445028#20445028

Comment: wait() doesn't do what you think it does.  I suggest you read the Javadoc for Object.wait();

Comment: I made it. I was idiot...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't suspend a thread execution by invoking `wait()` on it. `wait()` suspend the **current** thread until another thread calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the same object the previous thread called `wait()` on. Moreover, in order to call `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on an object, the calling thread must hold that *object's monitor* by doing

```
synchronized(object) {
    object.wait();
}
```

In order to suspend your counting, you need a flag and provide two methods to suspend and resume your counting. Something like:

```
class FirstCountDown extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    private _suspended = false;

    public synchronized void suspend() { _suspended = true; notify(); }
    public synchronized void resume() { _suspended = false; notify(); }

    public Integer doInBackground() {
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            synchronized(this) {
                while (_suspended) {
                    wait(); // The current thread will block until some else calls notify()
                            // Then if _suspended is false, it keeps looping the for
                }
            }
            CountDown.count1.setText(String.valueOf(1000-i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```